# CSS Different text box over image when hover at different different location

Tags: html, css, hover

I need to make an image of a map when a mouse is hover at certain location, a text box will appear on the map. When a mouse is hover at another location, a different text box will have to appear at a different part of the map.

```
---------------------------
| box 1             box 2 |
|           MAP           |
|                         |
| hover2           hover1 |
---------------------------
```

Say when the mouse hover over hover1, box 1 will apear.  When the mouse hover over hover2, box 2 will appear.

I was able to user css to do hover1 -> box1, but am unable to do the hover2 -> box 2.  Will I be able to achieve the result with CSS alone?

html:

```
<h1>World Map</h1>
<div class="map">
  <img src="assets/strangemap.png" usemap="#testing">
  <div>
    <map name="testing">
      <area shape="rect" coords="554,275,600,316" class="overlay">
    </map>
    <span class="text-content-left"><span>Midgaard</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.map {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 3px solid $gray-lighter;
  border-left: 3px solid $gray-lighter;
  border-bottom: 3px solid $gray-light;
  border-right: 3px solid $gray-light;
}

.overlay {
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.text-content-left {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 2px solid $gray-light;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

span.text-content-left span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.map map:hover + span.text-content-left {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: We could really do with seeing your code...

Comment: Create an [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)?

Comment: My apology...caffeine hadn't kick in yet :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woot!  Found a solution!

html:

```
<h1>World Map</h1>
<div class="map">
  <img src="assets/strangemap.png" usemap="#worldmap">
  <div>
    <map name="worldmap">
      <area shape="rect" coords="505,244,546,278" class="target" data-title="Text Box 1">
      <area shape="rect" coords="481,189,503,207" class="target" data-title="Text Box 2">
      <area shape="rect" coords="452,273,479,293" class="target" data-title="Text Box 3">
    </map>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
area[data-title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Now hovering on those coordinates will display the appropriate Text Box.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create an image map with context-sensitive hover areas.

These can be pretty complex, but here is a plugin that you might find useful:

http://www.outsharked.com/ImageMapster/default.aspx?demos.html#usa